# How to find misplaced Galaxy Buds Live with an iPhone SE 1st Generation?

Tags: iphone, bluetooth, headphones

I just got a pair of Galaxy Buds Live as they were a great price.  I understood that I cannot use the Galaxy app on my iPhone SE as it's too old, and that they would simply function as basic Bluetooth headphones, which is fine with me.  And they work great, I'm very happy with them thus far.

But now I've had one thought I'm unsure of an answer to.  These things are tiny, which is great until the inevitable happens and you drop one.  I got them in black, without considering that dropping them in a dark place, could be really bad.  Is there any way, since I can't run the Galaxy app, to engage any "find my headphones" type features?  Make them ping a sound?  Anything?  Or am I stuck with purely visual recognition of the little buggers?

Comment: You could find AirPods using Find My, but i don't think apple supports finding third-party devices..

Comment: Yeah I'm sure Apple's solutions wouldn't help here.  Was hoping maybe there's some clever trick specific to Samsung buds that would work on the older phones that can't run their app.  Not looking goo however, I'll just have to take major care not to lose them.